# Firebase Analytics don't detect Android and IOS Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-analytics

**Describe your environment**

- Operating System version: macOs Big Sur
- Expo version: 39
- Firebase SDK version: ^8.7.0
- Firebase Product: Analytics

**Describe the problem**

I followed the guide from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/

Where I created a project in firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/

then, I installed:

expo-firebase-analytics - ~2.5.0
firebase - ^8.7.0
expo-firebase-core - ^3.1.0

then, I updated my app.json with:

```
{
"expo":{
   "ios": {
      "icon": "...",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "...",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
},
    "android": {
      "icon": "...",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "...",
        "backgroundColor": "..."
      },
      "package": "...",
      "versionCode": ..,
      "permissions": []
    },
},
"web": {
      "config": {
        "firebase": {
          "apiKey": "...",
          "authDomain": "...",
          "projected": "...",
          "storageBucket": "...",
          "messagingSenderId": "...",
          "appId": "...",
          "measurementId": "..."
        }
      }
    }
}
```

then I did a test:

```
import * as Analytics from 'expo-firebase-analytics'

Analytics.logEvent('event-test', { test: 10 });
```

then I checked in https://console.firebase.google.com/ to see the devices, just detected the events comes from web, even when the test I did, was in IOS:

[image]

I tried to follow these guides:

- https://blog.expo.io/using-firebase-analytics-with-expo-222ca84e4d33
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2244

Comment: Did you do the test in the Expo Go app or in a standalone app? If in the Expo Go app, it will be logged as coming from web. But once you build a standalone app it will be logged as coming from iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new app in the firebase console for both IOS and Android and download the google file and put it in your expo project folder? It seems the development version works with web but you need to connect the IOS and Android versions via the google-service files for them to work properly in production. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/setup-native-firebase/